# Add specific policy rule to concrete user in gitlab using user_policy.rb

Tags: ruby, gitlab

I need autoreleaser (name of one user) be able to read pipelines (secret variables) in GIT.
I'm trying to solve that using policies in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/policies/user_policy.rb`

I don't know Ruby, but it should look like:

```
If (user == "autoreleaser") enable :read_pipeline
```

This is code in `user_policy.rb`

```
    class UserPolicy < BasePolicy
      desc "The current user is the user in question"
      condition(:user_is_self, score: 0) { @subject == @user }


      desc "This is the ghost user"
      condition(:subject_ghost, scope: :subject, score: 0) { @subject.ghost? }

      rule { ~restricted_public_level }.enable :read_user
      rule { ~anonymous }.enable :read_user

      rule { user_is_self | admin }.enable :destroy_user
      rule { subject_ghost }.prevent :destroy_user

    end
```

Comment: You don't need to know much ruby to do this. Just a tiny bit. Mostly it's about gitlab's API/DSL.

Comment: I still need help to write this pseudo code in RUBY "If (user == "autoreleaser") enable :read_pipeline"

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "you need to know gitlab's api/dsl". Should be similar to how ghost users are treated. `rule { subject_autoreleaser }.enable :read_pipeline`. You might need to add method `User#autoreleaser?` if it's not yet available.